# Using .NET/Mono on Linux to serve a high volume web service, a good idea?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

We have a web service that does a fairly high volume of traffic that helps you figure out what are your preferred contacts based on the e-mails you receive.

This service was initially implemented in C# /.NET in order to leverage some code we already have running on Windows hosts.  This service does not uses ASP.NET but it's a simple C# service using a base HTTP Listener from .NET.

The service is performing OK, but once in a while MONO will totally blocks and stop responding to any requests.  The performance is OK, but not great and it seams that we spend a huge amount of time figuring the difference between the MONO CLR and the Windows CLR.  I must admit, I am coming from a Java background and it seems that the ecosystem on the server side is way larger on the Java side than the MONO ecosystem on Linux.

So for now, I am looking for examples and personal experiences around using Mono on Linux to server a high traffic web service.

Comment: You might want to define "high volume".  Are you talking hundreds of requests per day? Thousands? Millions?

Comment: 4 to 5 Millions request per cluster per day.  We already have a sharding mechanism to split our user population into different clusters.  But the goal is to handle 4 to 5 Millions requests per day, per cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it will help to solve your problems, but you can try to run your web service on [mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8) which comes with [new garbage collector](http://www.mono-project.com/Generational_GC).

Comment: Good suggestion, we are using 2.6.4 now.  What's the status of 2.8 in general.  It's not mentioned here: http://www.mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Ubuntu.

Comment: If you want to have cutting-edge Mono versions, I suggest you either use an OS with packages directly available from Novell (http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) or build from source (http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments).

Comment: Version 2.8 should be released very soon (matter of days or weeks). I have mono build from git source (downloaded 30. August) and mono runtime version is 2.8.1 there. If you are using Ubuntu then the best choice for you is probably parallel mono environments or building it from daily tarball package.

Answer (score 0):

For high volume performance tuning, you often need to consider the following pieces altogether

- operating system settings (TCP/IP specific)
- web server level settings
- framework level settings (Mono specific)

Like @yojimbo87 described, using the latest Mono build can help burst the performance from framework level. But you also need to learn about the OS and the web server to see if there are other tuning approaches.